# SceneKit and NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: ios8, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver, scenekit

I am trying to archive my SceneKit scene for saving using NSKeyedArchiver. This is so I can save the scene allowing me to restore it at a later date. I am finding that the restored scene seems to ignore/lose the SCNTransformConstraints I have added to various SCNNodes. This results is the nodes being placed in the wrong place.

I am wondering if this is by design or a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you archiving it? Using `writeToURL:options:delegate:progressHandler:`?

Comment: I am using NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(scene). I don't think writeToURL:options:delegate:progressHandler is available in iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCNTransformConstraints works with a block provided by the client of the API. Blocks can't be archived with NSKeyedArchiver. 
You need to archive another object instead that is be able to reconstruct the block and re-assign the transform constraint.

Comment: It does seem that the Constraint is decoded and correctly associated with the SCNNode. But I guess the code block is no longer valid. Looks like I will need to recreate the constraints post decode. Thanks